# parameters errors from curve_fit do not match with manual computations in linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression, curve-fitting

Consider a set of dependent y variable data with errors yerr and the independent variable x, where errors are just the square root of the y  data.

```
#libraries
import numpy as np 
import math
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
#data
y=[157, 135, 121, 104, 86, 71, 83, 90, 67, 86]

y=np.array(y)
yerr= np.sqrt(y)
x=[0.5+i for i in range(0,len(y))]
x= np.array(x)
```

I want a linear fit: y=mx+b

Acoording to theory, the error for the parameter b is(this comes from the second derivative of the chi^(2) function: i leave a picture of the equation in the following link.

[image]

Where the sigma_{i} are the data error of y which i defined as yerr in the code. The computation is trivial and the result is:

```
berr= np.sqrt(1/(np.sum((yerr)**(-2))))

print(berr)

With the result 3.055923039288051
```

However, if i used curve_fit to directly compute the quantities:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#linear function definition

def linearFunc(x_fun,b,m):
    y_fun = b + m * x
    return y_fun

a_fit,cov=curve_fit(linearFunc,x,y,sigma=yerr,absolute_sigma=True)


intersection_b_error = np.sqrt(cov[0][0])

print(intersection_b_error)

7.0227762719525515
```

The result is 7.0227762719525515. Why are the results different? Is my formula for b error bad? or is it that curve_fit can not be applied to the data set maybe because is to small Thanks!

I tried the codes a lot of times, so now I would like your help.

Comment: I'm afraid your formula for the error on b is wrong. It does not just depend on the sigma's, but also on the x values. See, for example, the equations on slide 10 of https://phas.ubc.ca/~oser/p509/Lec_09.pdf.

Comment: thank you, just one question: how can the x appear in the formula, since after I derived twice by the parameter b, nothing left but the y errors. I would appreciate your help

Comment: I'm using the approach of calculating errors using second derivatives of the chi square

Comment: You need to substitute in the maximum likelihood values of m and b first, i.e., the values given on slide 7.

Comment: So, after substitution the partial derivatives are now with respect to the variables x and y, no longer m and b since they are not there anymore, am I correct?

Comment: The other option would be that the partial derivatives are still with respect to m and b, but now assume they depend on y data.

Comment: Yes, the partial derivatives used as the estimators for the uncertainties on m and b should only depend on the data and x-values and not on the variables m and b themselves.